# Active Directory: Is it possible to set invalid User Account Control values?

Tags: active-directory

To the best of my knowledge, my employer uses automated template scripts to provision new user accounts. I do not have access to these templates to review their logic. Based on my understanding of the User Account Control (UAC) value, there are pre-defined values provided by Microsoft. Additionally, new values can be created via a combination of other pre-defined values, which becomes its own new UAC value (see weblink below).

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms680832(v=vs.85).aspx

**Question 1:** Is it possible to create different combinations of permissions that result in a new duplicate UAC value?

**Question 2:** Is it possible to set a UAC value with an automated script that is neither a valid pre-defined value or combination value? For example, UAC value 4 is neither a valid pre-defined nor combination value.

Note: I do not have AD write permissions to test this. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: @GabrielLuci Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes and no. I tried both via AD Users and Computer and PowerShell `Set-ADUser`. Surprisingly, neither gives you an error, but neither method actually updates to an invalid value either.

Via PowerShell:

```
Set-ADUser $user -replace @{userAccountControl=4}
```

No error, but if I read it back, the attribute hasn't changed. If I do the same with a valid value (like 512 or 514) and read it back, I see the value changed.

In AD Users and Computers, I get no error, but if I close and reopen the account, it's set to 512, regardless of what it was set to before.

Comment: Can you take a look at a new post I put up? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51974186/ssis-active-directory-extract-getting-periodic-errors