# SSIS Active Directory extract getting periodic errors

Tags: c#, ssis, active-directory

I am running an Active Directory extract via SSIS Script Component and receiving the same error randomly:

> Error Code: -1073450910 Error Description:
>   System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryServicesCOMException (0x80072020):
>   An operations error occurred.
>
> at
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.ScriptComponentHost.HandleUserException(Exception
>   e)    at
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.ScriptComponentHost.PrimeOutput(Int32
>   outputs, Int32[] outputIDs, PipelineBuffer[] buffers)    at
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.ManagedComponentHost.HostPrimeOutput(IDTSManagedComponentWrapper100
>   wrapper, Int32 outputs, Int32[] outputIDs, IDTSBuffer100[] buffers,
>   IntPtr ppBufferWirePacket)

I am unable to isolate what is causing the problem because it is happening randomly in many environments: production, development, my own laptop.

When running the same script in the development application project, which makes it easier to identify what is causing problems, the problem goes away. When I re-run the application in development then it completes successfully.

Does anyone know what is causing this random error?

**Update**

I am running the job with an AD user account that is designated as a service account. I will note that there have been two phases to the project (I and II).

1. Phase I has been in for 2+ months with no problem.
2. When Phase II came up for release, which includes an enhancement to retrieve the `proxyaddresses` field, the problem started appearing intermittently. However, the new Phase II job was running in development for a month or two without problem. It wasn't until the day of the deployment (last Friday) did the problem first occur in the Stage environment.

Comment: Are you running the job with a domain account (not just the SYSTEM account)?

Comment: @GabrielLuci I have updated my question